# 404 error while trying to install g++ complier

Tags: apt, package-management

I recently installed VS code and I cannot download the g++ compiler. I type `sudo apt install g++` and it returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cpp cpp-7 g++-7 gcc gcc-7 gcc-7-base libasan4 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5
  libgcc-7-dev libgomp1 libisl19 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpx2 libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-7-locales g++-multilib g++-7-multilib gcc-7-doc libstdc++6-7-dbg gcc-multilib make autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc
  gcc-7-multilib libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan4-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg
  glibc-doc libstdc++-7-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cpp cpp-7 g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 gcc-7-base libasan4 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0
  libcilkrts5 libgcc-7-dev libgomp1 libisl19 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpx2 libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
0 upgraded, 30 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 987 kB/35.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 155 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.15.0-29.31
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.15.0-29.31
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-29.31_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have tried running `apt-get update` and tried deleting the sudo g++ file and reinstalling it, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Do you get any errors in `sudo apt update`.  The package you're trying to download is out-dated, so I suspect you have something wrong with your sources (such as non-Ubuntu), or use a mirror that is last-update-unknown (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) or aren't using Ubuntu (is that why you haven't told us your release?)

Comment: Everything guiverc says is correct.  In addition to what was said, it looks like you're having problems accessing that IP address.  Can you `ping 91.189.88.161`?  And also try going to `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` via a web browser?  Both should work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need to setup a correct DNS server to resolve these urls.

```
sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then add google DNS for example:

```
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

After that run 
    sudo apt-get update

Then proceeds with your normal install.

Answer (score 0):

put this first to install linux-libc-dev package which you can't download

```
TEMP_DEB="$(mktemp)" &&
wget -O "$TEMP_DEB" 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-49.53_amd64.deb' &&
sudo dpkg -i "$TEMP_DEB"
rm -f "$TEMP_DEB"
```

then start `sudo apt-get install gcc`.